# Where do you usually put authenticated variable in the react frontend?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So usually in a website where you're required to log in there's `authenticated` variable stored somewhere to tell the component to render a specific thing for an authenticated user only. Where do you usually store it?

I tried storing it in redux or regular state with this solution usually the state is defaulted to `false` and you will check the backend authentication in the `useEfect` hook to see if the user is authenticated and if it's true you set the `autheticated` state to true. The problem I have with this however is let's just say the user refreshes the page the state will reset and for a split second the state would be `false` again and that could cause the page to render somethings it shouldn't

So how do you properly and safely store your `autheticated` variable ?

Comment: You can keep your authenticated status in global state , by doing this whole part of your application will have access to that state.

Comment: Since you're using redux, you could try redux-persist.

Comment: You might wanna store in `localstorage`, `sessionstorage` or `cookies`

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw I've never heard of `sessionStorage` but about the rest I could be wrong but can you modify `localStorage` and `cookies` via console and isn't that a security risk?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal does global state resets when you refresh the page ?

Comment: @Melly global state resets after page you refresh the whole application but not refresh when you are redirecting from one route to another

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal That's my problem. global state is just another way of doing redux